# How do I get the Resource Usage view using the PSI 2007

Tags: project-server, psi

Please excuse me if I use incorrect terms or concepts. Seems I am in the mist of a crash course on MS Project, Project Server, and the PSI...

Project Professional provides the Resource Usage view that lists a given Resource, the Tasks they have been assigned to, and the amount of scheduled Work for a given day.

Is this information available in Project Server and how would I read it using the PSI?

Thanks.

- Jason

Answer (score 1):

If you're just getting started with PSI, I'd strongly recommend downloading and [using the ProjTool app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa494895%28office.12%29.aspx) that is part of the [Project 2007 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=2672F6F9-7028-4B30-99A2-18CB1EED1ABE&displaylang=en).

I haven't done too much work with Resources, but after taking a quick look.. here is how I'd approach it:

1. Reference the [Project.asmx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms503195%28office.12%29.aspx) service (ex: http://servername/pwa/_vti_bin/psi/Project.asmx)
2. Use the [ReadProjectEntities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcproject.project.readprojectentities.aspx) method to retrieve a DataSet and pass it a `ProjectEntityType` of `Task`, `Assignment` and `Resource`.

Define some entity types:

```
public const int ENT_TYPE_TASK = 2;
public const int ENT_TYPE_RESOURCE = 4;
public const int ENT_TYPE_ASSIGNMENT = 8;
```

Then you can read the data:

```
int entity = ENT_TYPE_TASK | ENT_TYPE_ASSIGNMENT | ENT_TYPE_RESOURCE;
ProjectDataSet dataSet = project.ReadProjectEntities(projectUid, entity, DataStoreEnum.PublishedStore);
// do stuff with these tables...
//dataSet.Task
//dataSet.Assignment
//dataSet.ProjectResource
```

ReadProjectEntities is nice because you can read only the part of the project you need... if you need more than the Task table then you can use a logical OR to get additional `ProjectEntityType`s.

As for the assigned work, it looks like that is also in the Assignment table, but I think you'll have to do some calculating.

Comment: Thanks for responding Kit. I actually downloaded the SDK several days ago...I even modified it and added additional services to it. I do not have a problem reading Projects, Tasks, Resources, or even Assignments. After further research it looks I may have found the data I was looking for in the [MSP_EpmAssignmentByDay] table in the Reporting database.